# XeTeX: problem with g-brief2 and polyglossia

Tags: xetex, polyglossia

Today I discovered a problem with the [`polyglossia`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia) package and the [`g-brief2`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/g-brief) class. I hope someone can help me to fix it. :)

Here is my `polyglossia` MWE (`polyg.tex`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{g-brief2}
\usepackage
{%%
    fontspec,
    polyglossia,
    lmodern,
    relsize
}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}

\Name               {My Name}
\Unterschrift       {My Name}
\Betreff            {Subject}
\Datum              {\today}
\Anrede             {Dear,}
\Gruss              {Regards,}{0.5cm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{g-brief}
        bla bla bla
    \end{g-brief}
\end{document}
```

The log for compiling (`xelatex polyg.tex`) contains the following message:

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.18 ^^I\begin{document}
```

So, where is the problem? – Best regards and thanks for your assistance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: The `g-brief2` class forces the loading of the `inputenc` package, and since this package cannot be used with either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you can't use the class with these engines. The class also forces loading of `babel` which isn't a good idea if you are also loading `polyglossia`.

Comment: @AlanMunn Please make that an answer

Answer (score 3):

With TeX Live 2013 I get no error, but, of course, loading both `babel` and `polyglossia` can raise some conflicts.

If you avoid loading `babel`, you get around the error also with older TeX distributions:

```
%%% Fool LaTeX to have already loaded babel
\makeatletter
\@namedef{ver@babel.sty}{2001/03/01}
\@namedef{opt@babel.sty}{\sprache}
\makeatother
%%% End of trick

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{g-brief2}
\usepackage
{%%
    fontspec,
    polyglossia,
    relsize
}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}

\Name               {My Name}
\Unterschrift       {My Name}
\Betreff            {Subject}
\Datum              {\today}
\Anrede             {Dear,}
\Gruss              {Regards,}{0.5cm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{g-brief}
        bla bla bla
    \end{g-brief}
\end{document}
```

Ask the maintainer of `g-brief2` an option for avoiding `babel`.